Are there any positive integers $n$, $k$ such that $n > 2, k > 6$, and all prime factors of $n^k - 1$ are less than $n$?
I noticed that the prime factorization of $68^6 - 1$ is $3^2 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 13 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 23 \cdot 31 \cdot 67$, which makes all of its prime factors less than 68. This made me wonder the original question in the title: is 6 the maximum possible exponent?
Sidenote - I actually first wondered: What positive integers $n$ exist such that all prime factors of $n^6 - 1$ are less than $n$? I did find certain values of $n$ that satisfy this: $68, 159, 230, 263,\dots$

The question is equivalent to asking for which values of $n,k$ is the polynomial $n^k - 1$ $(n-1)$-smooth, which heuristically must happen quite often. Probably one can prove that for fixed $k$ a typical polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients of degree $k$ there will be infinitely many positive integers $n$ for which $f(n)$ is $(n-1)$-smooth.

8777^8 - 1 == 2^6 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 19 * 41 * 89 * 97 * 101 * 401 * 617 * 857 * 1097 * 1697 * 1777

@hoboonsuan so cool, how did you find this?

@WilliamHu I ran the Mathematica command Select[Range[2, 100000], FactorInteger[#^8 - 1][[-1, 1]] <= # &]; the sequence begins 8777, 9308, 10181, 14971, 18283, 23343, 26097, 26659, 34229, 34887, 36843, 50802, 52158, 55924, 59895, 62497, 62511, 67707, 67765, 68479, 72061, 74172, 75954, 84229, 86519, 91499, 91515, 92564, 92777, 92879, 97311, 98505, 99198, 99523 ….
Also, the k=3 case is on the OEIS (https://oeis.org/A081258) (well actually it's the <=n case rather than <n); and the cumulative sums of the sequence 68, 159, 230, 263, ... look very close to a quadratic function when plotted.

For k=7 and k=10, there are no results* up to n=10^5. For k=9 there is only one result up to n=10^5, namely 45796.
(*caveat: there is a chance that some results were missed out because Mathematica may stumble on pseudoprimes)

@hoboonsuan My intuition did tell me that if there were results, it would probably be for k=8, but k=7 would be harder to get.

@hoboonsuan Also, note that if you wanted to check (n, k), you don't have to completely factorize n^k-1; you can just keep trying to divide by p for all primes p < n, and see if the result is 1. Maybe that will speed it up.

174037^7 - 1 == 2^2 * 3 * 43 * 463 * 491 * 3361 * 5657 * 9479 * 13217 * 13693 * 14503 * 87151

@hoboonsuan ahh turns out there is a related sequence! https://oeis.org/A074270 (however, this is with the cyclotomic polynomial, not with the entire n^k - 1)

For every integer $k\geq 1$, there exists an integer $n\geq 2$ such that all the prime factors of $n^k-1$ are less than $n$. This follows from a more general result of Bober-Freitwell-Martin-Wooley (2020), see Theorem 2.1 in their published paper or their arXiv preprint.
The proof is simple. Fix an integer $r\geq 2$ such that $\varphi(r)/r<1/k$, e.g. let $r$ be the product of all primes less than $e^k$, and then consider $n=t^r$ for an integer $t\geq 2$. Note the factorization
$$n^k-1=t^{kr}-1=\prod_{d\mid r}\Phi_d(t^k),$$
where $\Phi_d$ is the $d$-th cyclotomic polynomial. This factorization implies that the largest prime factor of $n^k-1$ can be bounded as
$$P(n^k-1)\leq\max_{d\mid r}\Phi_d(t^k)\ll_r t^{k\varphi(r)}=n^{k\varphi(r)/r}.$$
The exponent on the right-hand side is less than $1$ by the choice of $r$, whence $P(n^k-1)<n$ holds for every sufficiently large integer $t\geq 2$.
